# Ag Grid how to set filter server side from code

Tags: filter, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have Ag grid with Angular in my project and I added filters to the grid.

```
 function ServerSideDatasource(server, projectListComponent) {
      return {
    
        getRows: function (params) {
          
          var response = server.getData(params.request).then((res) => {
...
```

When I choose sample filters in columns headers the params.request.filterModel returns json (two filter were choosen):

```
"{
"ProjectID":{"filterType":"number","type":"equals","filter":10,"filterTo":null},
"ProjectName":{"filterType":"text","type":"equals","filter":"P"}
}"
```

And it works.
But I want to assign above json to filter of Ag grid when view is loaded at the start?
I want to set filters at the begin by assigning json with predefined values.

I try to in this way, but it doesn't work:

```
var jsonText = "{ \"ProjectID\": { \"filterType\": \"number\", \"type\": \"equals\", \"filter\": 10, \"filterTo\": null },"
      + "\"ProjectName\": { \"filterType\": \"text\", \"type\": \"equals\", \"filter\": \"P\" }"
      + "} ";
    var jsonFilter = JSON.parse(jsonText);

    this.gridApi.rowModel.filterManager.allFilters = jsonFilter;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setModel method for filter

```
    let filterComponent = this.gridApi.getFilterInstance('ProjectID');    
    filterComponent.setModel({    
          type: "equals",    
          filter: 10    
        });    
   this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
```

And then set the other field filter in the same way.